# How to convert Resultset object to String in Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring

```
I am getting the below output after executing the query.
I am getting in Object format, but i need in String format.
I want to get list of the ResultSet.

private static final String GET_PROPERTY_VALUE = "select property, value \r\n" + 
            "      from metadata \r\n" + 
            "      where id = ?";

public List<String> getTransformationValue(Long documentId) throws ABCApplicationException{

        List<String> names = null;
        try {
            names = jdbcTemplate.query(GET_PROPERTY_VALUE, new Object[] { documentId },
                    new RowMapper() {
                  public Object mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

                           resultSet.getString(1);
                           resultSet.getString(2);

                      return resultSet.toString();
                  }
                });                 
        } catch (DataAccessException dae) {
            logger.error(dae.toString());
            throw new ABCApplicationException(dae).setParameter("SQL", GET_PROPERTY_VALUE);
        }
        return names;
    }
```

even though after converting into the toString(), getting the same result. 
The Output is:
`property - org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet@6fd70563, 
value - org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet@6fd70563`

Instead of the above Object format, I want to get like below String format.
`property - First Name, Last Name
value - Ram, Robert`

Comment: Start with this `return  resultSet.getString(1) + " " + resultSet.getString(2);`

Comment: Also, use `...new RowMapper<String>()...`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting the method `jdbcTemplate.query` to return a List of Strings, I suggest you use a [SingleColumnRowMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/SingleColumnRowMapper.html) instead of a simple RowMapper. Something like this:

```
new SingleColumnRowMapper<String>(String.class)
{
    public String mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException
    {
        return resultSet.getString(1); // Chose here your desired reading formula
    }
}
```